# Integration and FTC

Tags: integration

Guys I didn't understand how to attack this kind of problem, for example:

Given that $$  \int_0^1xf''(2x)dx=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^2xf''(x)dx \ \ (i)$$ 
and $ f(0) =2, f(2)= 4$ and $ f'(2) =5$, calculate the followig:
$$ \int_0^1xf''(2x)dx \ \ (ii)$$

Here is what I'm trying to do:
I take the RHS from $(i)$ and integrate by parts
$$\frac{1}{4}\int_0^2xf''(x)dx=\frac{1}{4}( \ xf'(x)|_0^2 \ -\int_0^2f'(x)dx \ ) = \frac{1}{4}(2f'(2)-\int_0^2f'(x)dx)$$

But we have $$ 2f'(2)-\int_0^2f'(x)dx = 2f'(2)-\int_0^xf'(x)dx+\int_2^xf'(x)dx$$
Then applying the FTC
$$ 2f'(2)-\int_0^xf'(x)dx + \int_2^xf'(x)dx= 2f'(2) + f(x) - f(x)=2f'(2) = 2\times5 = 10   $$
Plugging it into the RHS of (i), we have
$$ \frac{1}{4}\int_0^2xf''(x)dx = \frac{10}{4} $$

Is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite, your penultimate line:

$$ 2f'(2)-\int_0^xf'(x)dx + \int_2^xf'(x)dx= 2f'(2) + f(x) - f(x)=2f'(2) = 2\times5 = 10   $$
should be

$$ 2f'(2)-\int_0^xf'(x)dx + \int_2^xf'(x)dx= 2f'(2) - f(x)+f(0) + f(x)-f(2)=2f'(2) = 2\times5+2-4 = 8   $$

Giving you a final answer of $2$ instead

Your method however was spot on and it will work for all questions of the same type.

In some cases however, including perhaps this one it is easier to find such a function $f$.

Clearly from the integral formula given $f''(x)=ax$ would satisfy the formula
so we get $f(x)=\frac{ax^3}{6} + \frac{bx}{2} +c$
and by subbing the given values in we're left with $f(x)=\frac{x^3}{2} - \frac{x}{2} +2$

So $$\int_0^{1}xf''(2x)dx=[2x]_0^1=2$$

Comment: Yes, it's easier to solve finding a function $f$ but I was trying to understand how the mechanism above works, anyway, thank you for replying me, I forgot completely that I had to throw the limits of the integral. Ty :))